# Translate sentence into FOL expression, confused about constants and quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic

Translate the following statements into FOL sentances

1) **Alex likes John**

*Likes(alex, john)* - I know this is correct

2) **Each person is either a man or woman**

*AxAy( man(x) v woman(y) )*

**EDIT: Is this better??:** *Az(Person(z) -> man(x) v woman(y))*
**OR EDIT: Is this better??:** *Ax(Person(x) -> man(x) v woman(x))*

3) **No one is both man and woman**

*Ex( (man(x) ^ ¬woman(x)) v (¬man(x) ^ woman(x)) )*

4) **Alex likes a man who likes a woman**

*AxEy(Likes( man(x), woman(y) ) -> Likes(alex, man(x) ))*

Thanks

[Here is a screenshot of the background info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU7dj.png)

**EDIT: For number 3,** I have found this online
"The exclusive disjunction of p and q asserts that either p is true or q is true but not both. The natural, but long-winded, way to express exclusive disjunction, then, is (p | q) & ~(p & q)."

If this can apply, then I assume the correct answer is Ax( (man(x) v woman(x)) ^ ¬(man(x) & woman(x)) )

But now I am getting confused as to how 2 and 3 are different...

Comment: I do not quite understand your reasoning. Could you please explain your translations.

Comment: Connectives:
¬ negation ‘not’ /
^ conjunction ‘and’ /
v  disjunction ‘or’ /
A universal quantification ‘for all …’ /
E existential quantification ‘for some …’ (Yes A and E should be upside down, but with a normal keyboard this is as close as I get, should be understandable though)

Comment: An example from my book: Every rich man loves Jane.

Comment: Ax.((Man(x) ^ Rich(x)) -> Loves(x, jane))

Comment: the arrow -> means implication

Comment: @DmitriChubarov - so for "Each person is either a man or woman", I was thinking it has to be "A" meaning for all, since I assume when they say "each person" they mean everyone, so that is why I used the universal quantifier "A"... but I think it is wrong which is why I am asking for help. It seems like I wrote the equivalent of "for all x and all y, either x is male or y is female?" which would be wrong then...

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I have edited two of them above and hope they are maybe better? Hope this is all understandable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hey I just wanted to know if these were correct

### 1. Testing the Correctness of Translation

One of the ways to test if a first order sentence agrees with an informal specification is to use a model.

To perform a test you need:

1. To determine how many relations are there in your first order sentence and list them. This list would play the role of the logical signature of your model.
2. Now take a set of individuals large enough to have all interesting combinations of properties assigned to at least one individual.
3. Assign the properties to individuals according to your understanding of the meaning of relations in your first order sentence.
4. Finally for each universally quantified variable try different assignments of individuals to variables and check if the property holds.

Consider one of the examples from the post.

**Informal specification**: *Alex likes a man who likes a woman*

We have

- one constant symbol: **Alex**
- two unary relations: **Man(x)** and **Woman(x)**
- a binary relation: **Likes(x,y)**

#### 1.1 Structure No. 1

Now consider a structure where we have an individual for Alex, an individual for a man who is not Alex, and an individual for a woman who is not Alex.

Let's start with three: p1, p2, p3.

- Alex is p1
- Man(p2)
- Woman(p3)
- Woman(p1)
- Likes (p2,p3)
- Likes (p1,p2)

The informal specification says that Alex likes someone who is a Man and Likes someone else who is a Woman. Our model satisfies this specification.

Now consider the following statement taken from the OP:

```
AxEy(Likes( man(x), woman(y) ) -> Likes(alex, man(x) ))
```

This statement is from a different language. Here *man(x)* and *woman(y)* are unary functions instead of unary relations, so we cannot check this sentence.

I would not speculate any further on the subject of *woman(y)* or *man(x)* being a function (Pun intended). Instead I would consider a different sentence.

```
AxEy(Man(x) & Woman(y) & Likes( x, y ) -> Likes(alex, x ))
```

Let's see what happens if x=p2 and y=p1. In our model the premise

```
Man(p2) & Woman(p3) & Likes( p2, p3 )
```

holds, and the conclusion

```
Likes(p1,p2)
```

also holds, therefore the formula is true under this variable assignment.

#### 1.2 Structure No. 2

Now consider a different model. This time with four individuals: p1,p2,p3,p4.

- Alex is p1
- Man(p2)
- Man(p4)
- Woman(p3)
- Woman(p1)
- Likes (p2,p3)
- Likes (p1,p2)
- Likes (p4,p3)

This model also satisfies our informal specification as Alex likes p2 who is a Man and likes p3 who is a Woman.

Consider the assignment x=p4 and y=p3.

Once again the premise holds in our model

```
 Man(p4) & Woman(p3) & Likes( p4, p3 )
```

however the conclusion

```
 Likes(p1,p4)
```

does not hold in our model. Since `x` is universally quantified this might be a problem as the formula does not hold under this assignment, however `y` is under an existential quantifier. Let's see if we can find an assignment for `y` that would turn our formula into a true statement with `x=p4`.

This is indeed possible. Let `y=p2`.

```
 Man(p4) & Woman(p2) & Likes( p4, p2 )
```

does not hold, therefore the formula

```
 Man(p4) & Woman(p2) & Likes( p4, p2 ) -> Likes(p1,p4)
```

is true. This sounds better yet to satisfy the formula we took an assignment that is far from the intended meaning of the informal specification. The original specification clearly was not speaking about a man who likes another man. So we are not done yet.

#### 1.3 Structure No. 3

Consider a model with just two individuals: p1 and p2.

- Alex is p1
- Man(p2)
- Woman(p1)

The informal specification does not hold in this model, so our sentence also should be false. There are four possible assignments of variables

- x=p1,y=p2
- x=p1,y=p1
- x=p2,y=p1
- x=p2,y=p2

Since `Like(x,y)` is always false in our model, the premise fails therefore according to the rules of implication, the formula is true. So our sentence is also true in a model where it should not hold. Once again, our first-order formalization does not hold against the informal specification.

This seems to be a very complex process that we have taken to test the translation. It assumes a certain skill of finding counterexamples and always keeping in mind the intended meaning of the informal specification.

### 2. How to Come up with a Correct Translation

Let's look back at our informal specification

**Informal specification**: *Alex likes a man who likes a woman*

and reformulate it in a way that is easier to translate

*There exists a man whom Alex likes, and this man likes some woman*

There are two parts in this sentence connected with an *and*

1. Ex (Man(x) & Likes(Alex,x))
2. Ey (Woman(y) & Likes(x,y))

So we have

Ex (Man(x) & Likes(Alex,x) & Ey (Woman(y) & Likes(x,y))).

You like prenex normal forms where all quantifiers are collected in one quantifier prefix. We can apply logical equivalence to get

ExEy (Man(x) & Likes(Alex,x) & Woman(y) & Likes(x,y)).

Now let's check if this statement agrees with the specification in each of the structures from the previous section.

#### 2.1 Structure 1

Since the variables are existentially quantified and the specification holds, we need to find only one satisfying assignment for the formula.

Consider

- Alex is p1
- x = p2
- y = p3

The conjunction holds under this assignment.

#### 2.2 Structure 2

The same assignment as in the previous subsection can be used. In fact
Structure 1 is an *substructure* of Structure 2. For an existentially quantified statement we know that if it is true in a substructure, it is also true in the whole structure.

#### 2.3 Structure 3

Since there is no pair of elements `(x,y)` such that `Likes(x,y)` in our structure, the conjunction

```
 Man(x) & Likes(Alex,x) & Woman(y) & Likes(x,y)
```

cannot be true, so the statement is false. We also know that Structure 3 does not satisfy our informal specification, so our formula has passed our tests.

Our testing procedure is by no means complete. However it gives us some assurance that the translation is indeed correct.

Comment: This was my previous exam which I already took, I am just trying to figure out if the answers which I gave were correct since I am retaking the exam because I did not get a good grade.

Comment: I am not asking for anyone to complete this entire assignment but here it is just so you have a reference: Translate the following statements into FOL-sentences: 

Alex likes John. 
Alex likes Pat. 
John likes Pat. 
Pat likes Sue. 
Each person is either a man or a woman. 
No one is both man and woman. 
John is a man. 
Sue is a woman. 
Alex likes a man who likes a woman. 
(Note that the abbreviations Alex and Pat are gender-neutral, i.e. they may stand for Alexander/Alexandra, Patrick/Patricia respectively ).

Comment: Let KB be the knowledge base consisting of the sentences 1 – 8 above.

 

c)

Transform KB into clause form

 

d)

Show by resolution that KB entails the sentence 9. Use an answer predicate to determine who the man and the woman referred to in sentence 9 might be.

Comment: So I am just asking about part one, the direct translations.

Comment: According to my picture shown above, the following which you wrote would be correct. one constant symbol: Alex.
two unary relations: Man(x) and Woman(x).
a binary relation: Likes(x,y). Although we also have z as a variable.

Comment: How is AxEy(Likes( man(x), woman(y) ) a unary function? Is it because for example using predicate P, AxEy P(x,y), Ey is bound by Ax, therefor y must be skolemized a function of x. P(x,f(y)).

Comment: So in your example: AxEy(Man(x) & Woman(y) & Likes( x, y ) -> Likes(alex, x )). It would roughly translate to for all x, there exists and y, where x is a man, and y is a woman, and man x likes woman y, which implies that alex likes man x. I see how this is better :) Thanks!

Comment: I was just kind of thinking along the terms of if likes(x,y) is a predicate, then I can just replace x with man and y with woman, but I see how that doesn't work when you start adding quantifiers. I will keep that in mind for next time.